# Checking to see if Azure Virtual Machine is down

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-logic-apps

I am running a python script on Azure VM.  If the VM goes down i want to send an email notification so i know the script isn't running. I cant find a way for Logic Apps to do it.  Would it be easier to see if the script is no longer sending information?

Comment: What exactly are you worried about?  The script crashing (thus not sending anything) or the script crashing the VM?

Comment: If the VM crashes my script will stop but i need it to always be up.  The script is why i need the VM to not crash but i meant if the VM crashed for any reason.

Comment: The thing is, Azure VM's really don't randomly crash.  Have you looked into Availability Sets?

Comment: I am currently trying to use Task Scheduler right now

Answer (score 3):

You could use the HTTP request in Logic Apps to call the `Virtual Machines - Get` method to get the VM status. The URI would be like this:

`GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{vmName}?$expand=instanceView&api-version=2018-06-01`.

About the details, you could refer to this [site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/get). And the URI there is must $expand=instanceView parameters, cause the `statuses` is the property of instanceView.

And the logic app flow just like the below picture:

[image]

[image]

I Initialize variable to check the status, the input value is `@{body('HTTP')['properties']['instanceView']['statuses'][1]['displayStatus']}`, and in the condition judge the status value whether it's equal to `VM deallocated`. If the VM is running , the value would be `VM running`. If the value is `VM deallocated`, then will send an email to report the status.

[image]

Comment: @darkside,did you don't know how to mark the answer? On the left of my reply, there is an option to mark.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the bearer token will expire before long.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your python script is doing but one option is to use Application Insights.  This post shows how to monitor a Python App running in an Azure App Service but you could also use App Insights on an Azure VM.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/najib/2018/05/11/monitoring-python-applications-with-azure-app-insights/